# ESP8266 Panic crashing when updating HTML template though Serial communication with Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, iot, esp8266

I have basic knowledge of ESP and Arduino, I was writing a program to remotely start my 3 phase  motor. In the circuit 4 sensors are connected to Arduino and Sending data to nodemcu ESP8266 by serial communication. I want to display the sensor readings to a web page (Localhost) with Button, My code:

```c
// Import required libraries
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//D6 = Rx & D5 = Tx
SoftwareSerial nodemcu(D6, D5);

// include library to read and write from flash memory
#include <EEPROM.h>

// define the number of bytes you want to access
#define EEPROM_SIZE 1

// Set to true to define Relay as Normally Open (NO)
#define RELAY_NO    true

// Set number of relays
#define NUM_RELAYS  1

// Assign each GPIO to a relay
int relayGPIOs[NUM_RELAYS] = {5};

//Min Voltage
int minVol = 0;
int minCur = 0;
int livVol = 0;
int livCur = 0;
String values, sensor_data;
String vol1;
String vol2;
String vol3;
String cur1;


const char* ssid = "ESP";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "relay";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "state";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "led";

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html {font-family: Arial; display: inline-block; text-align: center;}
    h2 {font-size: 3.0rem;}
    p {font-size: 3.0rem;}
    body {max-width: 600px; margin:0px auto; padding-bottom: 25px;}
    .switch {position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 120px; height: 68px} 
    .switch input {display: none}
    .slider {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #ccc; border-radius: 34px}
    .slider:before {position: absolute; content: ""; height: 52px; width: 52px; left: 8px; bottom: 8px; background-color: #fff; -webkit-transition: .4s; transition: .4s; border-radius: 68px}
    input:checked+.slider {background-color: #2196F3}
    input:checked+.slider:before {-webkit-transform: translateX(52px); -ms-transform: translateX(52px); transform: translateX(52px)}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Switch</h2>
  %BUTTONPLACEHOLDER%
<script>function toggleCheckbox(element) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(element.checked){ xhr.open("GET", "/update?relay="+element.id+"&state=1", true); }
  else { xhr.open("GET", "/update?relay="+element.id+"&state=0", true); }
  xhr.send();
}</script>
%PHASE%

</body>
</html>
)rawliteral";





String relayState(int numRelay){
  if(RELAY_NO){
    if(digitalRead(relayGPIOs[numRelay-1])){
      return "";
    }
    else {
      return "checked";
    }
  }
  else {
    if(digitalRead(relayGPIOs[numRelay-1])){
      return "checked";
    }
    else {
      return "";
    }
  }
  return "";
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Arduino Serial communication
  nodemcu.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

  // initialize EEPROM with predefined size
  EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE);

 // Set all relays to off when the program starts - if set to Normally Open (NO), the relay is off when you set the relay to HIGH
  for(int i=1; i<=NUM_RELAYS; i++){
    pinMode(relayGPIOs[i-1], OUTPUT);
    if(RELAY_NO){
      digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[i-1], HIGH);
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[i-1], LOW);
    }
  }

  digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[0], EEPROM.read(0));
  digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[1], EEPROM.read(0));
  digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[2], EEPROM.read(0));
  digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[3], EEPROM.read(0));


  WiFi.softAP(ssid);

  // Print ESP8266 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/update?relay=<inputMessage>&state=<inputMessage2>
  server.on("/update", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String inputMessage;
    String inputParam;
    String inputMessage2;
    String inputParam2;
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/update?relay=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1) & request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_1;
      inputMessage2 = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
      inputParam2 = PARAM_INPUT_2;
      if(RELAY_NO){
        Serial.print("NO ");
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[inputMessage.toInt()-1], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[0], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[1], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[2], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[3], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        EEPROM.write(0, !inputMessage2.toInt());
        EEPROM.commit();
      }
      else{
        Serial.print("NC ");
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[inputMessage.toInt()-1], inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[0], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[1], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[2], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[3], !inputMessage2.toInt());
        EEPROM.write(0, !inputMessage2.toInt());
        EEPROM.commit();
      }
    }
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
      inputParam = "none";
    }
    Serial.println(inputMessage + inputMessage2);
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/Led?led=1
  server.on("/Led", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    
    request->send(200, "text/plain", String(digitalRead(relayGPIOs[0])));
  });
  // Start server
  server.begin();
}
  
void loop() {

  if(livCur<<minCur & livVol<<minVol & digitalRead(relayGPIOs[0])==0){
        Serial.print("Off");
        digitalWrite(relayGPIOs[0], 1);
        EEPROM.write(0, 0);
        EEPROM.commit();
  }

  bool Sr =false;

  if(nodemcu.available()){
    
        //get sensor data from serial put in sensor_data
        sensor_data=nodemcu.readString(); 
        Sr=true;    
        delay(1000);
        
    }
  
delay(1000);

  if(Sr==true){  
    
  values=sensor_data;
  
  //get comma indexes from values variable
  int fristCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',');
  int secondCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', fristCommaIndex+1);
  int thirdCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', secondCommaIndex + 1);
  int fourthCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', thirdCommaIndex + 1);
  
  //get sensors data from values variable by  spliting by commas and put in to variables  
  String vol1 = values.substring(0, fristCommaIndex);
  String vol2 = values.substring(fristCommaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
  String vol3 = values.substring(secondCommaIndex+1, thirdCommaIndex);
  String cur1 = values.substring(thirdCommaIndex+1);

  }

  

}

// Replaces placeholder with button section in your web page
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "BUTTONPLACEHOLDER"){
    String buttons ="";
    for(int i=1; i<=NUM_RELAYS; i++){
      String relayStateValue = relayState(i);
      buttons+= "<h4>Motor</h4><label class=\"switch\"><input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"toggleCheckbox(this)\" id=\"" + String(i) + "\" "+ relayStateValue +"><span class=\"slider\"></span></label>";
    }
    return buttons;
  }

  if(var == "PHASE"){
    String phaseread ="";

    if(nodemcu.available()){
  String values="";
  String sensor_data="";
  sensor_data=nodemcu.readString(); 
  delay(1000);

  values=sensor_data;
  
  //get comma indexes from values variable
  int fristCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',');
  int secondCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', fristCommaIndex+1);
  int thirdCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', secondCommaIndex + 1);
  int fourthCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', thirdCommaIndex + 1);
  
  //get sensors data from values variable by  spliting by commas and put in to variables  
  String vol1 = values.substring(0, fristCommaIndex);
  String vol2 = values.substring(fristCommaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
  String vol3 = values.substring(secondCommaIndex+1, thirdCommaIndex);
  String cur1 = values.substring(thirdCommaIndex+1);

}
    
    phaseread+= "<h3>Phase 1:  " + String(vol1) + " </h3><br><h3>Phase 2:  " + String(vol2) + " </h3><br><h3>Phase 3:  " + String(vol3) + " </h3><br><h3>Current:  " + String(cur1) + " </h3><br>";
    
    return phaseread;
  }
  
  return String();
}
```

Everything works normally till I connected ESP8266 and Arduino and refreshed the Web page to check sensor values, it got crashed

```
Panic C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp:103 __yield

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffead0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 01b0
3fffec80:  3ffeec04 3ffeec04 3fffecc0 40209f01  
3fffec90:  3ffeec04 3ffeec04 3ffeec04 4020935d  
3fffeca0:  3ffe88aa 3fffed84 3fffecc0 402093e8  
3fffecb0:  3fffed90 3fffed84 3ffe88aa 40202dce  
3fffecc0:  3fff144c 0000001f 00000016 40100b8d  
3fffecd0:  00000000 402094cf 00000000 00000000  
3fffece0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffecf0:  3fff1434 0000000f 00000000 3fff141c  
3fffed00:  0000000f 00000000 3fff1b04 0000000f  
3fffed10:  00000000 000004d2 000004d2 401008ac  
3fffed20:  3fff1d58 3fffed65 3fffed84 40100cf0  
3fffed30:  3fff1d58 3fffed65 3fffed84 000001c5  
3fffed40:  3fff1d57 3fffed65 3fffed84 40209fac  
3fffed50:  3fff1ba4 00000000 3fff1a8c 40206ffc  
3fffed60:  53414850 4c500045 48454341 45444c4f  
3fffed70:  3ffe0052 00000000 00000000 3fff15f4  
3fffed80:  00007fff 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffed90:  3fff0c44 0000000f 00000005 00000001  
3fffeda0:  000001c6 3fff1d57 3fff1d5d 3fff1baa  
3fffedb0:  00000428 3fff1d70 3fff1fd1 0000008e  
3fffedc0:  3fffc278 4010297c 3fffc200 3fff1b1c  
3fffedd0:  00000430 40207264 00000430 3fff1b1c  
3fffede0:  3fff1ba4 00000000 3fff1a8c 40207295  
3fffedf0:  00000000 4bc6a7f0 b2b020c4 00000000  
3fffee00:  00000000 00000000 4bc6a7f0 00000000  
3fffee10:  3fff0ebc 00000001 00000430 00015c4f  
3fffee20:  00000000 3fff09be 3fff24ec 3fff0ebc  
3fffee30:  00000430 0000001c 3fff0ebc 4020a0ac  
3fffee40:  00000430 3fffee80 3fff0dd4 40203fb9  
3fffee50:  00000430 3fffee80 3fff0dd4 40207ed9  
3fffee60:  3ffef1d0 3fff0944 3ffef1c9 3ffef1e4  
3fffee70:  3fff0944 00000218 3fff0dd4 40208486  
3fffee80:  3fff0094 3fff0c2c 3fff13cc 3ffef1e4  
3fffee90:  3fff0944 3ffef1c8 3ffef1c9 40215c38  
3fffeea0:  4021f120 3fffdcc0 3ffe92a0 00000038  
3fffeeb0:  3ffef3ac 0104a8c0 00000048 40100afc  
3fffeec0:  00000000 00000036 3fffef30 3ffef3ac  
3fffeed0:  3ffef458 3fff13cc 3fff13ea 4021a8e5  
3fffeee0:  00000014 00000000 3ffef3ac 401008ac  
3fffeef0:  3fffdc90 3ffefddc 3fff1b04 3ffefe44  
3fffef00:  00000008 3ffef3ac 3fff13cc 402128e1  
3fffef10:  3fffdc90 3ffefddc 3fff1b04 40212717  
3fffef20:  40231c56 3ffefddc 3fff1b04 40231c67  
3fffef30:  3fff13dc 3fff13cc 00000000 3fffdcc0  
3fffef40:  4022c94b 00000000 3fff1b04 40233a17  
3fffef50:  40000f49 3fffdab0 3fffdab0 40000f49  
3fffef60:  40000e19 40001878 00000002 00000000  
3fffef70:  3fffff10 aa55aa55 00000011 40104dc4  
3fffef80:  40104dca 00000002 00000000 2a20712f  
3fffef90:  4010000d 8d009cd0 d6f0a078 ef40cead  
3fffefa0:  40100dc0 3fffef3c 40100d6d 3fffff18  
3fffefb0:  3fffffc0 00000000 00000000 feefeffe  
3fffefc0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefd0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffefe0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3fffeff0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff000:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff010:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff020:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff030:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff040:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff050:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff060:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff070:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff080:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff090:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff0f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff100:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff110:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff120:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff130:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff140:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff150:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff160:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff170:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff180:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff190:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1a0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1b0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1c0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1d0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1e0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff1f0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff200:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff210:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff220:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff230:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff240:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff250:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff260:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff270:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe  
3ffff280:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe
```

Can anybody please help?
It all started after I have added below lines in my code (For updating sensor values on web Page)

```c
  if(var == "PHASE"){
    String phaseread ="";

    if(nodemcu.available()){
  String values="";
  String sensor_data="";
  sensor_data=nodemcu.readString(); 
  delay(1000);

  values=sensor_data;
  
  //get comma indexes from values variable
  int fristCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',');
  int secondCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', fristCommaIndex+1);
  int thirdCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', secondCommaIndex + 1);
  int fourthCommaIndex = values.indexOf(',', thirdCommaIndex + 1);
  
  //get sensors data from values variable by  spliting by commas and put in to variables  
  String vol1 = values.substring(0, fristCommaIndex);
  String vol2 = values.substring(fristCommaIndex+1, secondCommaIndex);
  String vol3 = values.substring(secondCommaIndex+1, thirdCommaIndex);
  String cur1 = values.substring(thirdCommaIndex+1);

}
    
    phaseread+= "<h3>Phase 1:  " + String(vol1) + " </h3><br><h3>Phase 2:  " + String(vol2) + " </h3><br><h3>Phase 3:  " + String(vol3) + " </h3><br><h3>Current:  " + String(cur1) + " </h3><br>";
    
    return phaseread;
  }
```

EDIT: Decoded result

```
Decoding stack results
0x40209f01: __yield() at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\core_esp8266_main.cpp line 105
0x4020935d: Stream::timedRead() at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\Stream.cpp line 37
0x402093e8: Stream::readString() at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\Stream.cpp line 243
0x40202dce: processor(String const&) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\sketch_apr19a/sketch_apr19a.ino line 254
0x40100b8d: realloc at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1504
0x402094cf: String::changeBuffer(unsigned int) at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\WString.cpp line 156
0x401008ac: _umm_free at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1300
0x40100cf0: free at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1760
0x40209fac: std::_Function_handler ::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, String const&) at c:\users\Aman\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2/functional line 2058
0x40206ffc: AsyncAbstractResponse::_fillBufferAndProcessTemplates(unsigned char*, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer\src\WebResponses.cpp line 442
0x40100b8d: realloc at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1504
0x40207264: AsyncAbstractResponse::_ack(AsyncWebServerRequest*, unsigned int, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer\src\WebResponses.cpp line 300
0x40207295: AsyncAbstractResponse::_ack(AsyncWebServerRequest*, unsigned int, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer\src\WebResponses.cpp line 315
0x4020a0ac: AsyncWebServerRequest::_onAck(unsigned int, unsigned int) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncWebServer\src\WebRequest.cpp line 201
0x40203fb9: std::_Function_handler ::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data &, void *, AsyncClient *, unsigned int, unsigned int) at c:\users\Aman\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9\xtensa-lx106-elf\include\c++\4.8.2/functional line 2073
0x40207ed9: AsyncClient::_sent(std::shared_ptr &, tcp_pcb*, unsigned short) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncTCP\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp line 557
0x40208486: AsyncClient::_s_sent(void*, tcp_pcb*, unsigned short) at C:\Users\Aman\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESPAsyncTCP\src\ESPAsyncTCP.cpp line 753
0x40215c38: tcp_input at core/tcp_in.c line 469
0x40100afc: malloc at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1673
0x4021a8e5: ip4_input at core/ipv4/ip4.c line 710
0x401008ac: _umm_free at C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.0\cores\esp8266\umm_malloc\umm_malloc.c line 1300
0x402128e1: ethernet_input_LWIP2 at netif/ethernet.c line 188
0x40212717: esp2glue_ethernet_input at glue-lwip/lwip-git.c line 430
0x40231c56: ethernet_input at glue-esp/lwip-esp.c line 363
0x40231c67: ethernet_input at glue-esp/lwip-esp.c line 371
```

Comment: use the stack decoder plugin to decode the stack dump

Comment: I have added the decoded result in question @Juraj

Comment: you have a very old esp8266 arduino core. it could be any bug.

Comment: I think you had the problem of heap fragmentation causing by over-used/improper use of String and running out of memory, looking at the code block that you added, it has quite some unnecessary use of String, I would suggest you read my answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75758/40646) to have better understanding of heap fragmentation and then re-factor your code.